# Accuracy from sess.run(() is returning the value in bytes. How can I change to value?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am new to CNN and tried to train the CNN model. However when I try to print the accuracies returned from cnn it gives me results in bytes format like b'\n\x11\n\naccuracy_1\x15\x00\x00\x80<'. However when I try to print the values from the loss_train obtained from the same sess.run I get value of 1419.06. Why is this happening.

```
########################################################################################################################

#IMPORT PACKAGES

import math
import shutil
import pywt
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pip
import os 
from os import system
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.io as io
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import time
np.random.seed(1)
slim = tf.contrib.slim
########################################################################################################################

########################################################################################################################

#The FLAGS are used to assign constant values to several paths as well as variables that will be constantly used.

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('dataset_dir','E:\\CODING\\CNN_Compressed\\Trial\\Codes\\using_numpy\\NWPU-RESISC45\\NWPU-RESISC45\\','E:\\CODING\\CNN_Compressed\\Trial\\Codes\\using_numpy\\NWPU-RESISC45\\NWPU-RESISC45\\')
flags.DEFINE_float('validation_size', 0.1, 'Float: The proportion of examples in the dataset to be used for validation')
flags.DEFINE_float('test_size', 0.1, 'Float: The proportion of examples in the dataset to be used for test')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_shards', 1, 'Int: Number of shards to split the TFRecord files into')
flags.DEFINE_integer('random_seed', 0, 'Int: Random seed to use for repeatability.')
flags.DEFINE_string('tfrecord_filename', None, 'String: The output filename to name your TFRecord file')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('target_image_height', 256, 'train input image height')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('target_image_width', 256, 'train input image width')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128, 'batch size of training.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_epochs', 30, 'epochs of training.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.001, 'learning rate of training.')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
img_size = 256
num_channels=3
num_classes=45

########################################################################################################################

########################################################################################################################

datapath_train = 'E:\\CODING\\CNN_Compressed\\Trial\\Codes\\using_numpy\\NWPU-RESISC45\\NWPU-RESISC45\\train\\None_train_00000-of-00001.tfrecord'

def _extract_fn(tfrecord):
    features={   
            'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/channels': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)
            }

    parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord, features)

    image_de = tf.io.decode_raw(parsed_example['image/encoded'],tf.uint8) 

    img_height  = tf.cast(parsed_example['image/height'],tf.int32)
    img_width   = tf.cast(parsed_example['image/width'],tf.int32)
    img_channel = tf.cast(parsed_example['image/channels'],tf.int32)
    img_shape = tf.stack([img_height,img_width,img_channel])
    label = tf.cast(parsed_example['image/class/label'],tf.int64)

    image  =  tf.reshape(image_de,img_shape)

    #label  =  parsed_example['image/class/label']

    return image, img_shape, label

########################################################################################################################

#########################################################################################################################
"""
# Pipeline of dataset and iterator  
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(datapath)

  # Parse the record into tensors.
dataset = dataset.map(_extract_fn)

# Generate batches
dataset = dataset.batch(1)

# Create a one-shot iterator
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
image, img_shape, label = iterator.get_next()  
with tf.Session() as sess:
  try:
    print(sess.run(img_shape))
    image_batch=sess.run(image)
    print(image_batch)
    img_bas=tf.cast(image_batch,tf.uint8)
    plt.imshow(image_batch[0,:,:,:]*255)
    plt.show()
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      pass"""
########################################################################################################################

########################################################################################################################
#INITIALIZATION FOR THE CNN ARCHITECTURE

filter_size_conv1 = [5,5]
num_filters_conv1 = 32
filter_shape_pool1 = [2,2]
filter_size_conv2 = [3,3]
num_filters_conv2 = 64
filter_shape_pool2 = [2,2]

#PLACEHOLDERS
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, img_size,img_size,num_channels], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape= [None], name = 'ytrue') #Output data placeholder
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y,45)
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_one_hot, dimension=1)

########################################################################################################################

########################################################################################################################
def new_conv_layer(input, num_input_channels, filter_size, num_filters, name):

    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        # Shape of the filter-weights for the convolution
        shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters]

        # Create new weights (filters) with the given shape
        weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))

        # Create new biases, one for each filter
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[num_filters]))

        # TensorFlow operation for convolution
        layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input, filter=weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

        # Add the biases to the results of the convolution.
        layer += biases

        return layer, weights

def new_pool_layer(input, name):

    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        # TensorFlow operation for convolution
        layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=input, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

        return layer

def new_relu_layer(input, name):

    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:

        # TensorFlow operation for convolution
        layer = tf.nn.relu(input)

        return layer


def new_fc_layer(input, num_inputs, num_outputs, name):

    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:

        # Create new weights and biases.
        weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_inputs, num_outputs], stddev=0.05))
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[num_outputs]))

        # Multiply the input and weights, and then add the bias-values.
        layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases

        return layer

# CONVOLUTIONAL LAYER 1
layer_conv1, weights_conv1 = new_conv_layer(input=x, num_input_channels=3, filter_size=5, num_filters=32, name ="conv1")

# Pooling Layer 1
layer_pool1 = new_pool_layer(layer_conv1, name="pool1")

# RelU layer 1
layer_relu1 = new_relu_layer(layer_pool1, name="relu1")

# CONVOLUTIONAL LAYER 2
layer_conv2, weights_conv2 = new_conv_layer(input=layer_relu1, num_input_channels=32, filter_size=5, num_filters=64, name= "conv2")

# Pooling Layer 2
layer_pool2 = new_pool_layer(layer_conv2, name="pool2")

# RelU layer 2
layer_relu2 = new_relu_layer(layer_pool2, name="relu2")

# FLATTEN LAYER
num_features = layer_relu2.get_shape()[1:4].num_elements()
layer_flat = tf.reshape(layer_relu2, [-1, num_features])

# FULLY-CONNECTED LAYER 1
layer_fc1 = new_fc_layer(layer_flat, num_inputs=num_features, num_outputs=1000, name="fc1")

# RelU layer 3
layer_relu3 = new_relu_layer(layer_fc1, name="relu3")

# FULLY-CONNECTED LAYER 2
layer_fc2 = new_fc_layer(input=layer_relu3, num_inputs=1000, num_outputs=45, name="fc2")

# Use Softmax function to normalize the output
with tf.variable_scope("Softmax"):
    y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(layer_fc2)
    y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, dimension=1)


# Use Cross entropy cost function
with tf.name_scope("cross_ent"):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=layer_fc2, labels=y_one_hot)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)


# Use Adam Optimizer
with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 1e-4).minimize(cost)

# Accuracy
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls, y_true_cls)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# setup the initialisation operator
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Pipeline of dataset and iterator  
dataset_train = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(datapath_train)


# Parse the record into tensors.
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(_extract_fn)


# Generate batches
dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
iterator_train = dataset_train.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element_train = iterator_train.get_next()


print('\n Starting the CNN train')

# Initialize the FileWriter
writer_train = tf.summary.FileWriter("Training_FileWriter/")
writer_val = tf.summary.FileWriter("Validation_FileWriter/")

#summary
accuracy = tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
loss = tf.summary.scalar("loss", cost)

# Merge all summaries together
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

#PERFORM THE CNN OPERATIONS
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(iterator_train.initializer)


    # Add the model graph to TensorBoard
    writer_train.add_graph(sess.graph)
    writer_val.add_graph(sess.graph)

    # Loop over number of epochs

    print('\nTraining')

    for epoch in range(FLAGS.num_epochs):

        sess.run(iterator_train.initializer)
        start_time = time.time()
        train_accuracy = 0
        validation_accuracy = 0
        acc_train_avg = 0
        val_acc_avg = 0

        for batch in range(0, int(25200/FLAGS.batch_size)):

            img_train, shp_train, lbl_train = sess.run(next_element_train)
            _, loss_train, acc_train, acc_summ = sess.run([optimizer, cost, accuracy, merged_summary], feed_dict = {x: img_train, y: lbl_train})
            print(loss_train)
            print(acc_train)
            train_accuracy+=acc_train

        end_time = time.time()
        #acc_train_avg = (train_accuracy/(int(25200/FLAGS.batch_size)))
        #TRAINING
        print("Epoch "+str(epoch+1)+" completed : Time usage "+str(int(end_time-start_time))+" seconds")
        print("\tAccuracy:")
        print("\t- Training Loss:\t{}", loss_train)
        print ("\t- Training Accuracy:\t{}",acc_train)
        writer_train.add_summary(acc_summ,epoch+1)



#######################################################################################################################
```

The error is obtained as

```
Training
1427.1069
b'\n\x11\n\naccuracy_1\x15\x00\x00\x80<'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_trial.py", line 302, in <module>
    train_accuracy+=acc_train
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'bytes'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your loss and accuracy operations here:

```
accuracy = tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
loss = tf.summary.scalar("loss", cost)
```

Then when you run accuracy you get the protobuf bytes of the summary, instead of just running the op. You should rename these variables to prevent overwriting/name clashes.